# In Java, is constructor non static?

Tags: java, constructor

Many people say that constructor in java is Non-static..!
To initialize object we need Constructor. Therefore, we can use constructor without object then Constructor must be static.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to say/ask. Please try again

Comment: I think it's a nice philosophical question :) Constructor is kind of a strange method - it belongs to the class and to the new instance at the same time... So I understand the OP's point.

Comment: I think this was an attempt at a Question and Self-Answer, but it's unclear. If so, [edit] your question so that it just contains the question part (though you may want to add some detail about what caused the confusion) and then add an answer to the answer area.

Answer (score 4):

A constructor has an instance (`this` is available).  Therefore, it is, by definition, not static.

The JRE runs the constructor after it creates an instance.

Answer (score 1):

**Static members should be invoked with the class name**, without the need for creating an instance of the class, as in

```
ClassName.memberName/(..)
```

See good explanation :[Java static constructor – Is it really Possible to have them in Java?](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-constructor/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not about what "many people think" but rather about the definition. As the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) says:

> An **instance method** is always invoked with respect to an object, which becomes the current object to which the keywords `this` and `super` refer during execution of the method body.

and

> A method that is not declared `static` is called an **instance method**, and sometimes called a non-static method.

As you have `this` and `super` defined within the context of a constructor, you must consider the constructor as a **non-static** method, however I understand the idea behind your post that `new` bears some static features:

- you call `new` *before* you have an instance ready
- `new` is not virtual

Answer (score 0):

The constructor in Java is not use to *construct* an object, but to initialise the object. The constructor is the first method that is run by the JVM after the object is constructed of instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

In Java constructor can not be static or synchronized. An object will be constructed(creation+initialization) only by one thread at a time and constructor is run on already created instance - meaning in a non-static context.